# writing output to files from python luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I just tried to run the python luigi [example](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tasks.html#task-run) from the documentation:

```
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('xyz')

class FlipLinesBackwards(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return TaskA()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('abc')

    def run(self):
        f = self.input().open('r') # this will return a file stream that reads from "xyz"
        g = self.output().open('w')
        for line in f:
           g.write('%s\n', ''.join(reversed(line.strip().split())))
        g.close() # needed because files are atomic
```

I ran it using command line:

```
python Luigi_Test.py FlipLinesBackwards --local-scheduler
```

I was under the impression that this would create a file in the directory I am running it in but it doesn't?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there any execution errors in your terminal?

Answer (score 7):

The definition of `TaskA` doesn't make any sense. It probably is meant to be an `ExternalTask`.

```
class TaskA(luigi.ExternalTask):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('xyz')
```

That means that you have to write the contents of the file `xyz`

```
echo hi >> xyz
echo hello >> xyz
```

Then run the luigi workflow.